# Accessing recycle bin of a backed up drive

Tags: windows-10, backup, macrium, directoryopus

I have a backup of a drive made by Macrium Reflect which I have mapped as a drive to be able to browse it. Part of the backup is a $RECYCLE.BIN which I would like to explore but when I try to open it, I always end up in my local recycle bin. How can I access the backed up recycle bin?

I made three screenshots:

1. [The root directory of the backup](https://i.ibb.co/dmJP5FD/1.png)
2. [After clicking on recycle bin of the backup](https://i.ibb.co/s6wxZNz/2.png)
3. [My local recycle bin](https://i.ibb.co/QcSf389/3.png)

I tried to copy the recycle bin folder from the backup to my local storage and rename it but that didn't work either. I still end up in the local recycle bin with no files from the backed up recycle bin.

The files in the backed up recycle bin are definitely there because [when I hover with mouse over the folder a preview of its content is showed](https://i.ibb.co/hRktcpV/Clipboard-Image.png)  which corresponds with the backed up recycle bin and these files are not contained in my local recycle bin.

EDIT: I figured out a way to get to those files even though it is no the most elegant solution, it works. You just have to create an archive (I used WinRAR) with the backed up recycle bin and then extract just the files from inside of the archived recycle bin.

Comment: That shouldn't be happening. Can you include a screenshot of the backup disk's folders, and another of what happens when you click the folder?

Comment: So I made three screenshots: 1) [The root directory of the backup](https://i.ibb.co/dmJP5FD/1.png) 2) [After clicking on recycle bin of the backup](https://i.ibb.co/s6wxZNz/2.png) 3) [My local recycle bin](https://i.ibb.co/QcSf389/3.png)

Comment: @1605097435, do not add images in a comment, but edit the question with images inline.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for this PC was mounting the *Reflect* image, checking *Enable access to restricted folders* and *Make writable.* The file G:\$RECYCLE.BIN was then copied to a temporary folder, C:\temp, and opened in *Explorer*, where a number of subfolders were shown, all named *Recycle Bin*. The files in the subfolders, which had previously been deleted to the *Recycle Bin*, could then be **cut** from that folder and pasted into the outer folder C:\temp, where they could be opened. Note that it was *not* possible to open them while in *Recycle Bin*. Hopefully, this will work on your system.

My original thought was, if one mounts the Macrium *Reflect* image as a drive, what shows in the Windows *Recycle Bin* in Explorer *should* be the sum of everything in **all** the $RECYCLE.BIN files on **all** the mounted drives. However, the author of the question stated he had tried that and it *did not* work as expected

Comment: This is what I originally thought as well but in my case it is not working like that. Unfortunately there are ONLY files from my local recycle bin and no files from the backup. The oldest file in the recycle bin is just two weeks old whereas the backup is nearly a year old and on top of that it is a backup from another PC so the files cannot be the same.

Comment: @AlbertClarke, the answer has been revised, exploring $RECYCLE.BIN itself.

Comment: Unfortunately the new method doesn't work either.

Comment: Check out my question, I found a solution but a simpler one would be still appreciated.